# Finding neighbour vertices of a mesh inside a given radius

Tags: c++, mesh, point-cloud-library, cgal, point-clouds

How to get neighbour vertices of a mesh inside a given radius using, e.g., CGAL?
A simple K-nearest search on vertices neglecting face and edge properties is not sufficient, because if meshes are close to each other, vertices of both will be found using a k-nearest approach.

An example: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFasx.png]

blue -> query point, blue circle -> search radius, green -> vertices to be found, red -> wrongly found vertices by knn search, black -> mesh

Comment: This might work, define the distance from mesh center, consider both distances as a metric, then use KNN for example.

Comment: But doesn't that only work as long as the mesh is almost flat? I have added an example [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFasx.png). Could you clarify the approach using that image? Thanks.

Comment: Is it good enough for your application to walk on the edges of the mesh, stopping at the vertices that are too far?

Comment: I don't know about `CGAL`, but I saw some graph related classes there. Maybe you can convert your mesh to graph, then find neighbours on it..

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect. But I need an efficient mesh data structure. I do not really know which to chose of CGAL. Or if there is an implemented algorithm already.

Comment: A graph-based approach is maybe fast. I give it a try.

Comment: CGAL meshes can already be used as graphs, see the CGAL BGL package for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the CGAL BGL package and the function `CGAL::vertices_around_target`.

A brief example:

```
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> SCKernel;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<SCKernel::Point_3> SurfaceMeshT;
typedef SurfaceMeshT::Vertex_index VertexIndex;

[...]

std::shared_ptr<SurfaceMeshT> mesh;

[...]

void getVerticesAroundTarget(std::vector<std::size_t>& indices, 
                             std::size_t ptx) {
    VertexIndex vti(ptx);
    for (auto& idx : CGAL::vertices_around_target(mesh->halfedge(vti), *mesh)){
        indices.push_back(idx.idx());
    }
}

void getNeighbourVertices(std::vector<std::size_t>& neighbourVertices, 
                          std::size_t ptx, 
                          std::size_t idx, 
                          double searchRadius) {
    std::vector<std::size_t> indices;
    getVerticesAroundTarget(indices, idx);

    for (auto& vIdx : indices) {
        if (std::find(neighbourVertices.begin(), neighbourVertices.end(), vIdx) == neighbourVertices.end()) { // Vertex has not yet been treated.
            if (squaredEuclideanDistance(ptx, vIdx) <= searchRadius * searchRadius) { // Vertex in search radius.
                neighbourVertices.push_back(vIdx);
                getNeighbourVertices(neighbourVertices, ptx, vIdx, searchRadius); // Get next neighbours around vIdx.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
std::vector<size_t> neighbours;
double searchRadius = XXXX;
std::size_t ptx = XXXX;
getNeighbourVertices(neighbours, ptx, ptx, searchRadius);
```

launches the greedy search algorithm.